# How i can select element after some elements

Tags: javascript

I have some elements HTML and JavaScript but I can't selected the element after main element

```js
function LazyCate(i, s, a) {
  function g() {
    for (var g = document.querySelectorAll('.cate-sections .widget'), R = 0; R < g.length; R++) {
      var _ = g[R];
      if (_.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top < window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight || a) {

        if (s) var e = _.closest(s).offsetWidth,
          t = _.closest(s).offsetHeight;
        else t = _.hasAttribute('width') && _.hasAttribute('height') ? (e = Math.ceil(_.getAttribute('width')), Math.ceil(_.getAttribute('height'))) : _.hasAttribute('data-original-width') && _.hasAttribute('data-original-height') ? (e = Math.ceil(_.getAttribute('data-original-width')), Math.ceil(_.getAttribute('data-original-height'))) : (e = Math.ceil(_.parentNode.offsetWidth), Math.ceil(_.parentNode.offsetHeight));
        _.parentNode.classList.add('rendered');


        _.closest('.Item'); // i want select this after (var g *document.querySelectorAll('.cate-sections .widget')*)...


        $(".cate-sections .headline").fadeIn(500);

      }
    }
  }
  a ? g() : document.addEventListener('scroll', g)
}
LazyCate();
```

and this codes HTML ..

```html
<div class="widget HTML" data-version="2" id="HTML5">
  <h6 class="headLine">Title</h6>
  <div class="widget-content">
    <div class="item" />
    <!-- I want select this element after (class='widget') in top -->
  </div>
</div>
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Please can you provide non minified code in your example?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand you .. what do you mean?

Comment: Using indentation often helps when looking at HTML and figuring out child/sibling/parent relationships. Please format your code appropriately, and try out some things.

Comment: I just want to choose the `Item` tag which after the `Widget` tag how is it done in the example above

Comment: What does your LazyCate() function do?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, I want to correct the code so that it becomes the appropriate form in which to modify errors in the example above

Comment: My comment was not a question. I was asking you to do what I just did; format your code.

Comment: @Triby The `rendered` class is added to the `widget` tag if the scroll equals the first element, but i want select `Item` after `widget` class use javaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML `item` is **inside** the `widget`, so this should work

```js
var _ = document.querySelector(`.widget`)

var elItem = _.querySelector(`.item`)
// so just replace _.closest('.Item'); with _.querySelector(`.item`)

console.log(elItem)
```

```html
<div class="widget HTML" data-version="2" id="HTML5">
  <h6 class="headLine">Title</h6>
  <div class="widget-content">
    <div class="item"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case your `item` element **after** `widget` and on the same level as `widget` than

```js
var elItem = document.querySelector(`.widget + .item`)
console.log(elItem)
```

```html
<div class="widget HTML" data-version="2" id="HTML5">
  <h6 class="headLine">Title</h6>
  <div class="widget-content">
  </div>
</div>
    
<div class="item"/></div>
```